# SQL - joing tables - return value as null if not matched

Tags: mysql, sql

Evening, im not sure on what im asking here but I will try to explain. I'm not the best at SQL but I do try...

```
SELECT 
    qu.job_id, qu.engineer_id, qu.id AS `quote_id`, 
    jb.author, jb.image_ref, jb.job_title 
FROM 
    `ecom_quotes` qu, `ecom_jobs` jb 
WHERE 
    jb.author = 1 
AND 
    qu.job_id = jb.image_ref
GROUP BY 
    jb.image_ref
```

I used the above to list jobs posted by a user and getting other information from other tables based on the job id.

The problem being that if a job has no quotes posted for it, it does not display (qu.job_id = jb.image_ref).

So as a quick fix ( or so I thought ) i replaced it with

```
( ( qu.job_id = jb.image_ref ) OR ( jb.image_ref != '' ) )
```

which did work but it returns a quote id when there is no quote associated with it.

Is there anything i can do?

Comment: what about a `left join`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to use a [`LEFT JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/left-join-optimization.html).

This will still return a record for `ecom_jobs` even when there is no matching record in `ecom_quotes`.

EDIT:  Switched the order of the tables...

```
SELECT 
    qu.job_id, qu.engineer_id, qu.id AS `quote_id`, 
    jb.author, jb.image_ref, jb.job_title 
FROM 
    `ecom_jobs` jb
    LEFT JOIN `ecom_quotes` qu ON qu.job_id = jb.image_ref
WHERE 
    jb.author = 1
GROUP BY 
    jb.image_re
```

Comment: this again only brings back results if a quote is present... maybe Im rubbish at explaing! I can return all results for jobs by the user but only if someone has quoted on it. I want to be able to return jobs by the user even if a job has not had a quote

Comment: @PhilJackson Ahh.. My mistake - I think I get it now.  How does the new query work?

Comment: that is near on perfect, please explain what you have changed? Many thanks

Comment: And one other thing, what is the difference in using `left join` and doing it the way in my example?

Comment: The first query required a record in `ecom_quotes`, and would include a record in `ecom_jobs` if it existed... but this was the opposite of what you were asking for, so I changed the query to require a record in `ecom_jobs`, but make the matching record in `ecom_quotes` optional.  I could have also just changed it from a `LEFT JOIN` to a `RIGHT JOIN` and not changed the order of the tables, but `RIGHT JOIN`s are considered to be bad form.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try:

```
SELECT 
    qu.job_id, qu.engineer_id, qu.id AS `quote_id`, 
    jb.author, jb.image_ref, jb.job_title 
FROM 
    `ecom_quotes` qu 
LEFT JOIN
    `ecom_jobs` jb ON qu.job_id = jb.image_ref
WHERE 
    jb.author = 1 
GROUP BY 
    jb.image_ref
```

Comment: this again only brings back results if a quote is present